# A tricky for loop statment in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Please, help to understand this code:

```
a = b = 1
for i in range(1, 3):
 a, b = b, a + b
```

I couldn't understand 2 things:
1. How does it work? Does it assign i for 'a' and 'b'?
2. Why we need to assign 'a' and 'b' to 1 at the beginning? If we don't do it, this code returns error. Why?

TIA

Comment: ........ Because then there are no values to use in the computation.........

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. How does it work?

   1. This line sets `a` and `b` to 1

      ```
      a = b = 1
      ```
   2. This line iterates integers in the range [1, 3) (in this case, 1 and 2).

      ```
      for i in range(1, 3):
      ```
   3. This line is run for `i = 1` and `i = 2` and sets `a` to the value of `b` and sets `b` to the value of `a + b`.

      ```
      a, b = b, a + b
      ```

      Note, this could be rewritten as:

      ```
      tmp = b
      b = a + tmp
      a = tmp
      ```
2. Why we need to assign 'a' and 'b' to 1 at the beginning?

   Because if we don't, then `a` and `b` will be undefined and Python will not know how to evaluate `a + b`.

Comment: To the downvoter, why the downvote? Is there anything I can do to improve my answer?

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the '`for i in range(1,3)`' as a counter that simply runs the code in the for loop a set number of times (3). This is because i is never used in the expression located in the for loop.

We have to have the values of a and b assigned at the beginning or else we won't have any numbers to work with in the calculation below. Let's step through this to see if we can understand what is happening:

To start we know that both a and b are equal to 1.

**i=1:**

a = b so a = 1

b = a + b so b = 2

**i=2:**

a = b so a = 2

b = a + b **this uses the previous value of a** so b = 3

Now i will be greater than the range so the for loop will stop.

**So after the execution, a = 2 and b = 3.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is really usefull for me.